Change width reserved for stage manager when using the the Sequoia tiling keys?
MacOS Sequoia introduced the tiling keys (i.e., ctrl-option-left to place the current window on the left side of the screen). This helpfully leaves space for the stage manager.
For my taste, this space is a little too wide. I do not mean the width of the minimized windows in the stage manager area, but the offset of the resized window from the left screen border when using the aforementioned hotkey (and other tiling functions that involve the left border).
Is there some option or setting that lets me modify this width? It would probably not be directly associated with the stage manager itself, but with the tiling functionality. I don't find such an option (or really any other settings regarding the tiling functions). Are there maybe defaults write ... commands for this?
